# How to install torchcrf and fix import error?

Tags: python, pytorch, pycharm

I am using Windows 11 pro x64, PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Professional Edition) - Build #PY-222.4167.33, built on September 15, 2022 . Python version:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.521]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhu>python
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

My code

```py
import argparse
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torchcrf
import transformers
from data import Dataset
from engines import train_fn
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--data_file", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--hyps_file", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
data_file = yaml.load(open(args.data_file), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
hyps_file = yaml.load(open(args.hyps_file), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    Dataset(
        df=pd.read_csv(data_file["train_df_path"]),
        tag_names=data_file["tag_names"],
        tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"], use_fast=False),
    ),
    num_workers=hyps_file["num_workers"],
    batch_size=hyps_file["batch_size"],
    shuffle=True,
)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    Dataset(
        df=pd.read_csv(data_file["val_df_path"]),
        tag_names=data_file["tag_names"],
        tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"], use_fast=False),
    ),
    num_workers=hyps_file["num_workers"],
    batch_size=hyps_file["batch_size"] * 2,
)
loaders = {
    "train": train_loader,
    "val": val_loader,
}
model = transformers.RobertaForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"],
                                                                   num_labels=data_file["num_tags"])
if hyps_file["use_crf"]:
    criterion = torchcrf.CRF(num_tags=data_file["num_tags"], batch_first=True)
else:
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=float(hyps_file["lr"]))
train_fn(
    loaders, model, torch.device(hyps_file["device"]), hyps_file["device_ids"],
    criterion,
    optimizer,
    epochs=hyps_file["epochs"],
    ckp_path="../ckps/{}.pt".format(hyps_file["encoder"].split("/")[-1]),
)
```

I install by PyCharm
[image]

I also install by command

```
pip install torchcrf
```

I also try

```
pip install pytorch-crf
```

but I am not success.

How to install `torchcrf` and fix import error?

Answer (score 3):

`pip install pytorch-crf` this worked for me just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Install

```
from TorchCRF import CRF
```

rewrite code

```py
import argparse
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import torch
from TorchCRF import CRF
import transformers
from data import Dataset
from engines import train_fn
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--data_file", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--hyps_file", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
data_file = yaml.load(open(args.data_file), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
hyps_file = yaml.load(open(args.hyps_file), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    Dataset(
        df=pd.read_csv(data_file["train_df_path"]),
        tag_names=data_file["tag_names"],
        tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"], use_fast=False),
    ),
    num_workers=hyps_file["num_workers"],
    batch_size=hyps_file["batch_size"],
    shuffle=True,
)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    Dataset(
        df=pd.read_csv(data_file["val_df_path"]),
        tag_names=data_file["tag_names"],
        tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"], use_fast=False),
    ),
    num_workers=hyps_file["num_workers"],
    batch_size=hyps_file["batch_size"] * 2,
)
loaders = {
    "train": train_loader,
    "val": val_loader,
}
model = transformers.RobertaForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"],
                                                                   num_labels=data_file["num_tags"])
if hyps_file["use_crf"]:
    criterion = CRF(num_tags=data_file["num_tags"], batch_first=True)
else:
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=float(hyps_file["lr"]))
train_fn(
    loaders, model, torch.device(hyps_file["device"]), hyps_file["device_ids"],
    criterion,
    optimizer,
    epochs=hyps_file["epochs"],
    ckp_path="../ckps/{}.pt".format(hyps_file["encoder"].split("/")[-1]),
)
```

Reference https://pypi.org/project/TorchCRF/